# Doctrine Repository class not found

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Getting strange error from Symfony2 + Doctrine. Class is in it's place, no typos.

```
 Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: "The class 'AppBundle\Repository\ORM\ImageRepository' was not found in the chain configured namespaces AppBundle\Entity" at /Users/macbook/Projects/stfalcon_test/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php line 37 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\Common\\Persistence\\Mapping\\MappingException(code: 0): The class 'AppBundle\\Repository\\ORM\\ImageRepository' was not found in the chain configured namespaces AppBundle\\Entity at /Users/macbook/Projects/stfalcon_test/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:37)"} []
```

Beginning of Entity class:

```
/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ORM\ImageRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Image
{
```

Beginning of Repository class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository\ORM;

use AppBundle\Repository\Interfaces\ImageRepositoryInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * ImageRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class ImageRepository extends EntityRepository implements ImageRepositoryInterface
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple. The error was in service class, because I wanted to inject repository into manager. There was my service file:

```
services:
    app.repository.orm.image_repository:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        factory: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', getRepository]
        arguments:
            - AppBundle\Repository\ORM\ImageRepository

    app.manager.image_manager:
        class: AppBundle\Manager\ImageManager
        arguments:
            - "@app.repository.orm.image_repository
```

And in first service there should be entity class in arguments, not a repository class! I've made this mistake by inattention. So first service definition should look look this:

```
app.repository.orm.image_repository:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    factory: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', getRepository]
    arguments:
        - AppBundle\Entity\Image
```